Что нужно сделать чтоб в Серпе Гугла показывалось мобильное приложение, которое размещенное на сайте?
Помогите пожалуйста. Есть сайт и только недавно создали мобильное приложение. Разместили его на сайт. Но в Серпе Гугла увидели у одного сайта в снипетах мобильное приложение с призывом к установке: https://prnt.sc/aYL1GEd29L5V как сделать также чтоб оно отображалось в результатах органической выдачи как на скрине?
